# How to confirm WiFi data is being used, not data plan?

Tags: wi-fi

How can I confirm that I am using data only on WiFi?

In other words, I am connected to WiFi at home and work, yet I get notices that I am close to hitting my data plan's max limit.  Is there a way to somehow confirm that my data is being sent via WiFi when at home/work?

When connected to WiFi, even if the signal strength is say 1% of the WiFi connection, it's my understanding that my cell data plan will *not* be used until the phone disconnects from the WiFi, correct?

I know there's a way to see the amount of data sent over WiFi and the Data Plan, but I'm wondering if there's a way to somehow confirm that I'm on WiFi and the data is actually being sent via WiFi, and not using my data plan at all (*without* turning off the Data Plan in settings).

I'm just basically trying to confirm that my data is all going over WiFi, and not Data Plan, when connected to a WiFi Router (with any signal strength).

Answer (score 2):

I use a Galaxy S5 running Android 6 (Marshmallow) and my phone has different icons for wifi and data.

[image]

[image]

My phone also has little arrows that turn white if there are packets are being uploaded or download.

You can see data usage by app in the data usage setting.

[image]

And if you find that an application decides to use a lot of background without telling/asking you, you can click on it, and disable background data.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I use those too to check what's being used. I have an "alarm" set up to notify when my data (not WiFi) goes over a certain amount. I was wondering if there was a more technical way to check, because it just "feels" (for lack of a better word) that while I am connected to WiFi, and the WiFi icon is showing, that data is still being used over the non-WiFi data connection.

Comment: Your Android will never lie about which wireless is being used, if there is no data symbol, data is not being used. The data usage page will show you a graph of data used. If you are using a data monitor, other than the one built into android, then it might also be recording data used on wifi as well.